# FBSDKAppInviteDialog asking for login instead of show the Invite dialog

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to implement Facebook App invite as par guideline https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-invites/ios But that here strange behavior happen as following.

I successfully login with Facebook and tapped on button for App invite.

```
- (IBAction)ActionAppInvite:(UIButton *)sender {


    NSLog( @"### running FB sdk version: %@", [FBSDKSettings sdkVersion] );

    FBSDKAppInviteContent *content =[[FBSDKAppInviteContent alloc] init];


    content.appLinkURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://fb.me/1111111111"];
    //optionally set previewImageURL
    content.appInvitePreviewImageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"my_invite_image.jpg"];

    // present the dialog. Assumes self implements protocol `FBSDKAppInviteDialogDelegate`
    [FBSDKAppInviteDialog showFromViewController:self withContent:content
                                 delegate:self];
}
```

After that appear web view dialog from Facebook but that said you must login first instead of show me the invite dialog. and Facebook documentation said login not required.

[image]

After that if i am logged in at that web view then if i logged out from my app and login with different account then `FBSDKAppInviteDialog` show me old account facebook friends :(

can any buddy tel me where i did mistake or i need to change anything i am using sdk virsion 4.8.

Comment: I hope you are clearing FBAccesToken when you log out

Comment: this is not related to accesstoken. i think so

Comment: showing old friends might be. Make sure you do this in your logout function [[[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init] logOut];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just got the figur it out. we need to set `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` like following:

[image]

And if you are testing in simulator then you get always following effor on click:

I've updated to Xcode 7 and the latest iOS SDK. I've added the appropriate entries in my app's plist:

enter image description here

My app's Facebook login works fine on device. However, on iOS 9 simulator, I'm getting:

```
-canOpenURL: failed for URL: "fbauth2:///" - error: "(null)"
```

So better to test you application on real device.